# ColdFusion server configuration

Tags: apache, coldfusion

Following the instructions in the Adobe link below I have reinstalled CF9 multiserver config and Apache web server.
My link

So now my root for localhost points to C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs. Everything works great.

So here is my question. I'm trying to get organized. I play with a few sites. Can I set up my /htdocs
folder like so below and have each site has their own root.

```
IE
htdocs
---Site1
---Site2
---Site3
```

Up till now I have been just moving the needed site into the htdocs equivalent (I was using built in server prior to this.
) when I need to work on it etc.

Surely this isn't the only solution? Do I handle this in CF Admin or Apache or both. What do you do to manage multiple sites?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to search for is VirtualHosting in Apache HTTPD. VirtualHosting is setting up Apache to host different domain names in different directories.

I would suggest taking a look at the ACME guide. I can't find the link right now, but you should be able to google it. It walks through setting up a development environment with Apache, ColdFusion, MySQL, and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup each virtual host in the apache conf file, reads the docs on this.
You will also need to use your local hosts file to setup domains to point to your local machine.

So if you eanted to use dev.mysite.com
Open the hosts file from c:\windows\system42\drivers\etc
You will need to run notepad as administrator on wondows vista or newer.

At bottom of file enter
127.0.0.1    dev.mysite.com

Save file
This domain will now resolve to your local machine.
You need to setup the same domain as your virtual host in apache now.

If you are running windows vista or windows 7 then I would suggest using Iis instead of Apache, much easier.